# Save a PCL specific view as image

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, lidar

I am new to C++ and the use of the Pointcloud Library PCL (https://pointclouds.org/). At the moment I am able to generate a viewer of the point cloud by using the `<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer>` and I was wondering if it would be possible to save an image of the current viewer "view".

Imagine I have a picture like the following:
[image]
At the moment I just take a screenshot manually of what it looks like. However, since I will be processing many point clouds, I would like to have a way to convert this "viewer view" to an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course I posted the question after researching online. However, I could not find the super easy solution available already in PCL.

You just need to use the function:

`void pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::saveScreenshot (   const std::string &     file    )`

Documentation [here](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#ac6fbe63d727c9f910c0fed5b373b88e4)

I hope this will be helpful for someone else in the same situation.